# How to get yes/no statistics from SQL of how often strings occur each

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to query a table from [BigQuery project HTTPArchive](http://bigquery.cloud.google.com/project/httparchive) by checking how often certain strings occur by a certain file type?

I was able to write a query for a single check but how to perform this query on multiple strings at once without needing to send the same query every time just with a different string check and process the ~800GB of table data every time?

Getting the results as array might work somehow? I want to publish in-depth monthly statistics to the public for free so the option to send those queries separately and get billed for querying of roughly $2000/month is no option for me as a student.

```
SELECT matched, count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio
FROM (
    SELECT url, (LOWER(body) CONTAINS 'document.write') AS matched
    FROM httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies
    WHERE url LIKE "%.js"
)
GROUP BY matched
```

Please note that this is just one example of many (~50) and the [pre-generated stats](http://httparchive.org/downloads.php) are not what I am looking for as it doesn't contain the needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH strings AS (
  SELECT LOWER(str) str FROM UNNEST(['abc', 'XYZ']) AS str
), files AS (
  SELECT LOWER(ext) ext FROM UNNEST(['JS', 'go', 'php'])AS ext
)
SELECT 
  ext, str, COUNT(1) total, 
  COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(body), str)) matches, 
  ROUND(COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(body), str)) / COUNT(1), 3) ratio
FROM `httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies` b
JOIN files f ON LOWER(url) LIKE CONCAT('%.', ext)
CROSS JOIN strings s 
GROUP BY ext, str
-- ORDER BY ext, str
```

You can test / play with above using [totally] dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies` AS (
  SELECT '1234.js' AS url, 'abc=1;x=2' AS body UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'qaz.js', 'y=1;xyz=0' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'edc.go', 's=1;xyz=2;abc=3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'edc.go', 's=1;xyz=4;abc=5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'rfv.php', 'd=1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tgb.txt', '?abc=xyz' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'yhn.php', 'like v' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ujm.go', 'lkjsad' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ujm.go', 'yhj' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ujm.go', 'dfgh' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ikl.js', 'werwer'   
), strings AS (
  SELECT LOWER(str) str FROM UNNEST(['abc', 'XYZ']) AS str
), files AS (
  SELECT LOWER(ext) ext FROM UNNEST(['JS', 'go', 'php'])AS ext
)
SELECT 
  ext, str, COUNT(1) total, 
  COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(body), str)) matches, 
  ROUND(COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(body), str)) / COUNT(1), 3) ratio
FROM `httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies` b
JOIN files f ON LOWER(url) LIKE CONCAT('%.', ext)
CROSS JOIN strings s 
GROUP BY ext, str
ORDER BY ext, str
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to bring in a table with the different strings.  This is the idea:

```
SELECT str, matched, count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio
FROM (SELECT crb.url, s.str, (LOWER(crb.body) CONTAINS s.str) AS matched
      FROM httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies crb CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 'document.write' as str UNION ALL
            SELECT 'xxx' as str
           ) s
      WHERE url LIKE "%.js"
     )
GROUP BY str, matched;
```

You would just add more strings to `s`.

Comment: Thanks but I get the error: Query Failed. Error: Field 'str' not found.

Comment: @NhanNguyen . . . Thank you for fixing this.

Comment: I only get it to work with one string, if I add more I get incorrect counts/ratios (plus how can I refer which data belongs to which string?): 
`SELECT s.str, s.str2, matched, matched2, count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio
FROM (SELECT crb.url, s.str, s.str2, (LOWER(crb.body) CONTAINS s.str) AS matched, (LOWER(crb.body) CONTAINS s.str2) AS matched2
      FROM httparchive.har.2017_09_01_chrome_requests_bodies crb CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 'document.write' as str, 'document.ready' as str2) s
      WHERE url LIKE "%.js")
GROUP BY s.str, s.str2, matched, matched2;`

Comment: @DevDavid . . . Additional strings need to be brought in as *rows* not *columns*.

Comment: Thank you for your help!